# CSS animation. But nothing is happening on Chrome. Normal header is shown

Tags: html, css

trying to do animation. But nothing is happening on Chrome. Normal header is shown.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
height: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.7;
color: #777;
padding: 30px;
}

header{
height: 95vh;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom,rgba(126,213,111,0.8), rgba(40,180,131,0.8)),url(../img/hero.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: top;
position: relative;

clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%);
}

.text-box{
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-40%,-50%);
}

.logo-box{
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 40px;

}

.logo{
height: 35px;
}

.heading-primary{
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main{
letter-spacing: 35px;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 60px;

animation-name: moveInLeft;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: 3;
/*animation-delay: 3s;*/
}

.heading-primary-sub{
display: block;
letter-spacing: 17.5px;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveInLeft{
0% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateX(-100px);
}
80%{
transform: translateX(10px);
}
100%{
opacity: 1;
transform: translateX(0);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">

        <title>Natours | Exciting tours for adventurous people</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class='header'>
           <div class='logo-box'>
            <img src='img/logo-white.png' alt='logo' class='logo'>
        </div>

        <div class='text-box'>
            <h1 class="heading-primary">
            <span class='heading-primary-main'>Outdoors</span>
            <span class='heading-primary-sub'>is where life happens</span>
        </h1>
        </div>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to perform animation such that the heading moves from left to right but nothing is happening as the heading is shown as it is. 
I used `@-webkit-keyframes` still nothing happened.
Used `@keyframes` nothing happened.
Is the problem with the browser(Chrome)?
Please can someone help me?
This animation in CSS i have recently started learning, but this error really demotivate to learn further.

Comment: which element you want to animate?

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, you should mark it as such. This will help other users as well

Answer (score 1):

With these changes it works for me perfectly fine -:

```
.heading-primary {
  animation: play 4s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    transform: translate(-100px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `transform` you can use `margin-left`:

```css
*{
margin: 0;
height: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.7;
color: #777;
padding: 30px;
}

header{
height: 95vh;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom,rgba(126,213,111,0.8), rgba(40,180,131,0.8)),url(../img/hero.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: top;
position: relative;

clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%);
}

.text-box{
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-40%,-50%);
}

.logo-box{
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 40px;

}

.logo{
height: 35px;
}

.heading-primary{
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary-main{
letter-spacing: 35px;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 60px;

animation-name: moveInLeft;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: 3;
/*animation-delay: 3s;*/
}

.heading-primary-sub{
display: block;
letter-spacing: 17.5px;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveInLeft{
0% {
opacity: 0;
margin-left: -100%;
}
100%{
opacity: 1;
margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">

        <title>Natours | Exciting tours for adventurous people</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class='header'>
           <div class='logo-box'>
            <img src='img/logo-white.png' alt='logo' class='logo'>
        </div>

        <div class='text-box'>
            <h1 class="heading-primary">
            <span class='heading-primary-main'>Outdoors</span>
            <span class='heading-primary-sub'>is where life happens</span>
        </h1>
        </div>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```